# Outlook Addin - Minified Ribbon Group Icon

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto

In my add-on I can create ribbon group and add buttons to it and everything looks great while the outlook window spans the entire monitor and has enough room to display everything. However when the outlook window is resized to be very small all the buttons from the group disappear and a  mini icon for the group gets displayed. This happens for all the standard ribbon groups as well mine but they all have nice small icons set for them when the group gets minified. How do i set this for my group.

[image]

Comment: Can you show us a picture of your ribbon and tell us which icons you want to use?

Comment: @UfguFugullu Thank you for responding. I added a picture. As you can see when the window is small all of the groups shrink and use small icons. Mine gets the default icon with a blue dot. I would like to be able to set that icon but cant find where or how to set it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the default microsoft office icons you should give a look to the `OfficeImageId` property of your ribbon button. For example I use the `RefreshAll` icon here:

[image: OfficeImageId in the designer view]

and the result will be something like this:

[image: Result of RefreshAll icon]

More informations about the [OfficeImageId](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.ribbon.ribbonbutton.officeimageid?view=vsto-2017) you can find in the microsoft docs.
In this article you find a link to the [icon gallery](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=220760). Download the word file and follow the instructions, so you get a full gallery of all default office icons.

**EDIT after comment**

Now I got your problem - you have multiple buttons in your group. If you use the default ribbon through the designer there is no way to set the group icon.

But you can convert your current Ribbon to a xml based ribbon. You can do it if you have opened the ribbon designer and click on the ribbon. On the property window you get blue help links, which propose you to convert your ribbon to xml. In the *german* version it looks like this:

[image: converting ribbon to xml]

The next step is to follow the instructions in the comments of the new generated `Ribbon.cs`.
Last thing is to customize your ribbon group in the `Ribbon.xml` and add the `imageMso="RefreshAll` for example.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<customUI onLoad="Ribbon_Load" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
    <ribbon>
        <tabs>
            <tab idMso="TabCalendar">
                <group id="GroupCalendar" label="Refreshing" imageMso="RefreshAll">
                    <button id="button1" imageMso="RefreshAll" onAction="Button1_Click" label="Sync List One" size="large" />
                    <button id="button2" imageMso="RefreshAll" onAction="Button2_Click" label="Sync List Two" size="large" />
                </group>
            </tab>
        </tabs>
    </ribbon>
</customUI>
```

I hope that this edit will help you.

Comment: The OfficeImageId doesn't appear to be a group property? Only that of the button I place in the group. I tried setting it for the button but that didn't seem make a difference when the group is resized to be small.

Comment: @Troublesum I have added a solution in my answer by using XML for customizing the icon of the ribbon group when collapsed